# ToC links to the wrong page of the references

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a problem with the linking from the contents to the references. The very last  line before `\end{document}` is `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]`. In the premeable I have

```
\usepackage[english]{varioref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={title},
  pdfauthor={author},
%  pdfsubject={},
  bookmarksnumbered=true,
  bookmarksopen=true
}
```

If I click on the ToC-entry references, I am not redirected to the references but to some Lemma I made at the page before the references. Maybe it is important: The references don't (and shouldn't) start at a new page.

I tried to rebuild the problem for a MWE, but I can't. Maybe you have some ideas.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\linespread{0.5}\begin{center}\LARGE\scshape\bfseries}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
\preauthor{\begin{center}\large\scshape\lineskip 0.5em\begin{tabular}[t]{l r}}
\postauthor{&}
\predate{\large\scshape}
\postdate{\end{tabular}\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
\usepackage[indentafter]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\centering\large\scshape}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat {name=\section,numberless}{\large\scshape\filcenter}{}{0pt}{}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}[1.5em]{\large}{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{1.5em}}{\hspace*{-1.5em}}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}[\vspace*{0.3em}]


%CROSS-REFERENCES
\usepackage[english]{varioref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={title},
  pdfauthor={author},
%  pdfsubject={},
  bookmarksnumbered=true,
  bookmarksopen=true
}
\usepackage[english]{cleveref}

%REFERENCES
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxnames=10,maxalphanames=10,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

Here I cite \cite{key}.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   
Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   
Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   
Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.   
Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.   
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.   
Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus.   

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Comment: With this information it is not really possible to say much. With the help of `\usepackage{tocbibind}` you should get the correct link to the bibliographies

Comment: you have given very few clues (which package defines `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]` for example? Also have you run latex often enough for page references to be stable?

Comment: I am working with biblatex. Sorry, I don't know what you need to know in order to help. Just ask :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle....`heading=bibintoc` is a `biblatex` feature ...

Comment: @R.A.: Do you have some explicit `\addcontentsline` for the `References`?

Comment: No, do I need this?

Comment: @R.A.: No, but that would have explained a wrong linking, eventually. We need a MWE, otherwise everything is guessing around, what we did already.... assuming this or suspecting that...

Comment: since you have a document with the bad behaviour it should be easy for you to make a small example. Start with a copy of the document and delete everything you can delete while still showing the effect, for example you can probably delete all the document content, then you can delete most of the packages you are using (which will not be needed once the body of the document is gone) check at each stage the problem still occurs, and when you have a complete small document you can add it to the question. If you delete something and the problem goes, then you've found the cause of the problem..

Comment: I suspect that  @R.A. used a way to make the References not to start on a new page and this code causes the problem

Comment: So I have added a MWE. The problem might by the titling part in the premeable because if I delete it the problem is gone.

Comment: @R.A.: Sigh, `titlesec` ...

Comment: So? :D Is there a way to fix the problem without modify the titlesec, titling things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loading quite so many packages all redefining the section heading code seems a bit optimistic but as far as I can see

```
\phantomsection
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

gives hyperref a bit of a hint not to link to the start of the document.

Comment: I found that you need `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` before `\phantomsection` too to make the link work correctly.